# pytest capturing all output to stdout

Tags: python, stdout, pytest

I test the 'current line' that's printed like this

```
def test_clear(capsys):
    out = capsys.readouterr()
    outputs_more_than_one_line()
    assert out.out == 'last line printed'
    # impossible to check previously printed lines?
```

However, I would like to check everything that was printed. I've considered monkeypatching `builtins.print`, but that doesn't seem robust (doesn't capture sys.write.stdout). Is there anyway this would be possible?

Comment: You can actually use -s flag for pytest to disable output capture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html) says:

> The `readouterr()` call snapshots the output so far - and capturing will be continued.

therefore you should call `readouterr` after print lines, not before:

```
def test_cap(capsys):
    for _ in range(2):
        print('outputs_more_than_one_line')
    out = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out.out != 'last line printed'
```